# How do I script a key combination in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to add a piece to my script that does Windows Key + 7
I've done a lot of searching, and have been unsuccessful in finding how to simulate holding down a key, and doing a combo in Powershell- at least, not for PS.
I'm using Powershell V5, and I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you have tried? Is this for a GUI environment or for the console?

Comment: AFAIK win+7 will run the 7th shortcut pinned in taskbar, so why don't you invoke the shortcut's target directly ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911195/powershell-sendkey-and-appactive-strangness above link will help you